# HBase column filter is not an early-out filter like row filter? what is the performance impaction?

Tags: database-design, filter, hbase, database-schema

**Context2**:
Also I don't really get why the **Scan** API don't have you to specify the start and end row key+column qualifier, since they store together in HFile. That makes you resort to use ColumnPrefixFilter and the weird thing is: "HBase the Definitive Guide" says it is not early-out filter(table 4-5) .

The word  "early-out" means a filter can return halfway the scanning, so without this ability means it has no way to know if there are keys ahead need to be filter-in.(RowFilter can.)

**My argument2**:
It's really weird that Column are already sorted in HFile but column filter don't exploit this advantage to know where it should early out the filtering.
and somewhere in this [blog](http://hadoop-hbase.blogspot.tw/2012/01/hbase-intra-row-scanning.html) it says:

> This where ColumnRangeFilter comes into play. This filter seeks efficiently into the row by seeking ahead to the first HBase block that contains the first KeyValue (or cell) for that column.

That argument is apparently evidence the filter can exploit the order structure of keys.

**Question2**:Why ColumnFilter or ColumnPrefixFilter can't early out like row type filter? if it is, then is it tell that we should always desire for designing a tall table?

Comment: Could you not just do a scan on your specified start/end row keys and then check the column value yourself? Then you can break your for/while loop and continue however you would want to? Or are you specifically asking why it's like that?

Comment: if I scan and check KeyValue on scan result , then that is on client side, hens not efficiency as what filter would do.